# Flexbox whitespace between elements and border depending on window size

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out how to fix a layout problem I'm experiencing with CSS and flexbox.
With certain window sizes, the flexbox leaves a gap between its border and the elements inside, showing the background of the flexbox.

My monitor is 1920x1080. I am using chrome.
When I maximize my window, the variable-width flexbox (at 60%) has no gaps or whitespace, and the background is not shown.
When I resize the window to half of my monitor (at 960x1080), there is a one-pixel gap between the border of the flexbox and the element within, somewhere on the box, always.

In the production code I'm using, the gap is on the left, but for some reason the gap in the code I've provided is on the right.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgOBpB

Does anyone know a solution for this? I want the contents to always fully fill the flexbox.
I think it may be related to having `flex-grow: 1` on both elements where half of the flexbox's width is not a round number. Thus, the elements settle on both being rounded down, and the sum being one off from the edge.

Thank you!

edit: You don't have to read past here if you know how to help, but I've provided a lot of additional details that may be helpful.

When I resize and my window hits 823 px, the elements leave a gap. However, when I resize and the window hits 831 px, the elements reach *one pixel too far*! How does this make any sense?
It also happens with `width: 50%` in place of `flex-grow: 1`.

Apparently, it also happens with just a flexbox and `flex-grow:1` on a single inner-element. The flexbox cannot appropriately resize the contents.

I think it may be directly related to the `overflow:hidden`, but I don't want to get rid of that functionality because of the rounded border.

**Most importantly, when I remove `transition: translateZ(0)` the gap disappears. However, that is the only way I know of keeping the `overflow: hidden` while animating the contents.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one answer. It seems the bug is directly related to flexbox, so I've changed the container to `display: table`.

I was trying to do this to get the element to be able to be anchored to the top or bottom and still be animated while not extending outside the boundaries of the border-radius.

I have solutions for anchoring individually-animated elements to both the top and bottom.

Top: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRvorw
Bottom: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrJNWK

Ignore the naming of the elements, I didn't rename them from the initial demo.